# How to filter SQL data with a dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I am just starting with SQL, PHP, and HTML and I plan to take some courses, but I need a basic working model before I can move forward. I have an SQL database that has a few fields. I can display this data without a problem. I would like to filter this data with a drop-down box. Currently, I have the drop-down box populated with a Select Distinct command. I can not seem to figure out the syntax to modify my SQL Select command to only show records that match my pull-down box. Ha, I will be the first to admit that I have no clue what I am doing, but my problem is that I might not know the term I need to look up how to solve my problem. Google and I are tight, but we just can't put our finger on this one. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

<body>
<form action='new1.php' method="get" name='fPIC'>
<select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_PIC" name="sPIC">

<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "**********", "pd4poc");

mysqli_select_db($link,'pd4poc');

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT PIC FROM dummydata order by PIC asc";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$menu=" ";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $menu .= "<option value=".$row['PIC'].">" .$row['PIC']. "</option>";
    }
echo $menu;


echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['PIC'] . "<td><td>" , $row['Reason'] . "<td><td>", $row['Status'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

 mysqli_close($link);
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="nPIC" value="Filter">
</form>
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "**********", "pd4poc");

mysqli_select_db($link,'pd4poc');

$query = "SELECT * FROM dummydata"; //need to be picked from the pull down
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>
        <th>PIC</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        <th>PlanApply</th>
        <th>HOT</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>\n";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . 
    $row['PIC'] . "<td>",
    $row['Reason'] . "<td>",
    $row['PlanApply'] . "<td>",
    $row['HOT'] . "<td>",
    $row['Status'] . "<td>",
    $row['Comments'] . "</td>\n</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($link);
?>

</body>
</head>
```

Comment: Is the dropdown a selector of data? For example, how does the selection of the dropdown correlate to your tables?

Comment: something like: `... where PIC='$_GET[sPIC]'` but dont use the raw get value for safety

Comment: This data will populate the dropdown from the same table. I really think that nogad has the right idea but the syntax isn't quite right. PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sPIC.